# If G is a commutative group, then Z(G)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can prove or disprove the following statement that is a commutative group?

```
If G is a commutative group, then Z(G) = {b ∈ G| ab = ba for all a ∈ G} is G.
```

I was tried as follows,

````
Since  =  =  for all  ∈ , ∈ () and so () ≠ 0

Let ,  ∈ (). Then  =  for all  ∈ .

 = b
b^-1 bc = b^-1 cb
cb^-1 = b^-1 cb b^-1
cb^-1 = b^-1 c    ∈ 

Hence ^−1 ∈ ()

Now (^−1) = (^−1) = (^−1) = ()^−1 = ()^−1 = (^−1) for all  ∈ g
^−1 ∈ ()

Hence () ≤ . By definition () is commutative, () is called the centre of g
```
````

Comment: Prove that $G$ abelian implies $G\subseteq Z(G)$.

Comment: What does make your confusion, which part is not clear?

Comment: Since  =  =  for all  ∈ , ∈ () and so () ≠ 0

Let ,  ∈ (). Then  =  for all  ∈ .

 = b
b^-1 bc = b^-1 cb
cb^-1 = b^-1 cb b^-1
cb^-1 = b^-1 c    ∈ 

Hence ^−1 ∈ ()

Now (^−1) = (^−1) = (^−1) = ()^−1 = ()^−1 = (^−1) for all  ∈ g
^−1 ∈ ()

Hence () ≤ . By definition () is commutative, () is called the centre of g